# Using wait_event_interruptible and wake_up_all together

Tags: c, locking, linux-kernel

For a class project involving scheduling processes using blocking and locks, we're supposed to use two kernel functions:

```
int wait_event_interruptible(wait_queue_head_t q, CONDITION);
void wake_up_all(wait_queue_head_t *q);
```

The explanation of wait_event_interruptible is:

> Blocks the current task on a wait queue until a CONDITION becomes true.
>
> This is actually a macro. It repeatedly evaluates the CONDITION, which is a fragment of C code such as foo == bar or function() > 3. Once the condition is true, wait_event_interruptible returns 0. If the condition is false, the current task is added to the wait_queue_head_t list with state TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE; the current process will block until wake_up_all(&q) is called, then it will re-check the CONDITION. If the current task receives a signal before CONDITION becomes true, the macro returns -ERESTARTSYS.

And the explanation of wake_up_all is:

> Wake up all tasks in the wait queue by setting their states to TASK_RUNNABLE.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how exactly these functions work and how to use them together.  For example, when does the CONDITION get checked?  Does wait_event_interruptible continuously poll, or does it only recheck the condition when wake_up_all is called?  This explanation is a little unclear.

If you could give an example of how to use these functions together that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Does wait_event_interruptible continuously poll, or does it only
>   recheck the condition when wake_up_all is called? This explanation is
>   a little unclear.

The whole point of a scheduler is to avoid polling in cases like this. What happens is precisely described in what you quoted : The condition is only rechecked on wake_up, ie for example if a given task is waiting for data to be produced :

- consumer check if data is available
- if not (ie condition false) it goes to sleep
  and is added to a wait queue
- retry when waked up

While on the producer side

- Once data is produced, set some flag, or add something to a list
  so that the condition evaluated by the consumer becomes true
- call wake_up or wake_up all on a waitqueue