# Wait_event_interruptible Vs wake_up_interruptible

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have doubt with reference to the execution of wait_event_interruptible and wake_up_interruptible.

Doubt 1: Suppose in wait_event_interruptible condition was made TRUE in that case Process state is directly changed to RUNNING state?

If Yes in that case is it not required to call wake_up ? What is the use of wake up in this case.

Doubt 2: If Another process has called wake_up for the question present in waiting state but still condition in wait_event_interruptible is FALSE what will happen in that case?

I have tried take reference from [Using wait_event_interruptible and wake_up_all together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254395/using-wait-event-interruptible-and-wake-up-all-together) thread but I did not find proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When the condition is already true, there is no need to wait.
   (The `wait_event`* functions check the condition also before they begin the actual wait.)
2. When the condition is still false, it will go back to sleep.

Comment: CL:Still my point is not clear, my query is suppose wait queue condition is made true in that case there is no need to call wake up ? What is use of wake up ? Can we wake up process on waiting queue irrespective of condition TRUE/FALSE using wake up call.

Comment: I am writing in brief to solve my confusion. Please suggest me what happen in below condition 1) Wait_event with Flag !=0 condition called 2) Some other process has set Flag = 1 3) In that case for loop in wait_event will exit and set current state as TASK_RUNNING. In this case Waiting process will start running without calling wake_up explicitly. ?

Comment: In that case if wait_event is totally dependent on condition in that case why do we need wake_up call ? Because if condition is False and wake_up is called in that case also process will not come out of wait queue due to condition.

Comment: Without `wake_up`, the loop would never exit.

Comment: #define __wait_event(wq, condition)      \
do {         \
 DEFINE_WAIT(__wait);      \
         \
 for (;;) {       \
  prepare_to_wait(&wq, &__wait, TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE); \
  if (condition)      \
   break;      \
  schedule();      \
 }        \
 finish_wait(&wq, &__wait);     \
} while (0)  "How loop will never exit without wake_up call because as per above code for loop is checking condition and if condition is true it will break the for loop and finish_wait call will change process state to TASK_RUNNING"

Comment: `schedule()` will not return.

Comment: But if condition is true in that case code will not reach schedule() call and for loop will get break with break; statement.

Comment: Yes. So what's your problem?

Comment: My point is if wait_event is waiting for one condition...and if condition gets TRUE so as per Kernel code for loop will get break and finish_wait() will call which change of state of process in waiting queue to TASK_RUNING so this case my question is, waiting process will start executing if condition gets TRUE so it means WAKE_UP call is not required to change process state to TASK_RUNING ?There is no dependency of wake_up call for each wait_event call.

Comment: The call to `wake_up` will cause `schedule` to return. The condition check will cause the loop to exit.